# How can I put image in React

Tags: reactjs, image

I want to upload image from files in my React application (I use create-react-app).It didn't show up and the error message appeared.

The error message is

> ./src/components/pages/TimeTable.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../dance.png' in '/Users/jolly/Desktop/Dance_School_Website-master/src/components/pages'

My files:

```
--public 
  --images
    --dance.png


import TimeTablePic from "../dance.png";

function TimeTable() {
    return (
        <>
            <img className="TimeTablePic" src={TimeTablePic} alt="TimeTable" />    
            <Footer2 />   
        </> 
    );
}

export default TimeTable;
```

Comment: You png doesn't have an `export` statement, so you can't `import` it.  You should just be able to use the path to your image in your `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use

```
<img className="TimeTablePic" src="images/dance.png" alt="TimeTable" />
```

Comment: no problem, accept the answer so other people can also try this